# Please prove the given expression

Tags: trigonometry

Where $\theta =\frac π7$,

$$4\cos\theta = \frac{4 \cos^2 \theta - 1}{2\cos^2 \theta - 1}$$

To prove RHS=LHS. (Begin from RHS not LHS)

It is a problem of trigonometry, and I have the solution of the problem. However, after seeing the solution, I don't quite understand how is one supposed to know how to approach this problem. My request is:

Don't just solve the problem, but also tell me from where do you come to know which approach would work. (Tell me from where do you come to know which trick or approach to be used to solution this problem.) And if possible please give both full subjective solution and short cut method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $\theta=0$, your equation claims $4=3$. I doubt that I can find a simple proof for that.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include all relevant information, such as a complete copy of the problem and the solution, and indicate exactly which portion of the solution confuses you. Also, please type up your posts properly. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is not an identity, it is an equation. (it holds only for some values of $\theta$)

Comment: Please review the question again I have edited the question and sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 2):

Using addition theorems, we find
$$\begin{align}\sin2\theta&=2\sin\theta\cos\theta,\\\cos2\theta &=2\cos^2\theta-1,\\
\sin4\theta&=2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta=4\sin\theta\cos\theta\,(2\cos^2\theta-1)\end{align} $$
and
$$\begin{align}
\sin3\theta&=\sin(2\theta+\theta)\\&=\sin2\theta\cos\theta+\cos2\theta\sin\theta\\
&=2\sin\theta\cos^2\theta+(2\cos^2\theta-1)\sin\theta\\&=\sin\theta\,(4\cos^2\theta-1).\end{align}$$
For $\theta=\frac\pi 7$, we have $4\theta = \pi-3\theta$, hence $\sin3\theta=\sin4\theta$ (we *have* to use a special property of $\theta$ somewhere after all). Thus we can equate the above expressions  to obtain
$$4\sin\theta\cos\theta(2\cos^2\theta-1)=\sin\theta\,(4\cos^2\theta-1) $$
and from this the desired equation by dividing by $\sin\theta\ne 0$ and $2\cos^2\theta-1\ne 0$.

---

**How did I know this approach would work?**

As all we know about $\theta$ is that after multiplication with $7$ we obtain $\pi$, one might be tempted to exploit $\cos7\theta=-1$ and/or $\sin7\theta=0$. The addition theorems allow us to express $\cos n\theta$ and $\sin n\theta$ as a polynomial in $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$. In fact, if we are primarily interested in $\cos\theta$, we can eliminate much of $\sin\theta$ by using the fact that $\sin^2\theta$ can be replaced with $(1-\cos^2\theta)$. Thus all sines and cosines of integer multiples of $\theta$ can be expressed as $P(\cos\theta)+Q(\cos\theta)\cdot \sin\theta$ with polynomials $P,Q$. Thus any known value for sine or cosine of a multiple of $\theta$ translates into a polynomial equation.
Well, at least this works if  the expression turns out to have either $P\equiv 0$ or $Q\equiv 0$, which requires a bit of luck (or does it?).

The shortcut I took instead of computing the degree $7$ polynomials for $\cos7\theta$ and/or $\sin7\theta$, was to note that using $\sin3\theta=\sin4\theta$ should give us an equation of only $4$th degree.

The whole thing becomes a lot simpler if you have [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) available.